# Is it safe to store only "folder-name/filename.jpg" information for files uploaded to Firebase storage?

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage

Right now, everytime I upload an image file to firebase storage, I get an url that looks like this:

```
https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/my-project.appspot.com/o/some-folder%2Ffile_name.jpg?alt=media
```

And I'm storing the full URL in my Firestore docs for the object that uses that image.

If I know that it will never change, I could save just the last part: `/some-folder%2Ffile_name.jpg?alt=media`

But I don't know if the first part could change for future uploads.

Since I'll be rebuilding the full URL on client, if the first part do change for future downloads, it will break my code.

Should I stick to storing the full URL? Or is it safe to assume that the first part of the Firebase Storage API will always be the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase gives no written guarantee that nothing will change for that URL.  The only "safe" thing to do is store the entire URL.  Or, store the path and call `getDownloadUrl` every time you want to manufacture a new URL.

Comment: Thanks Doug, which `path` are you talking about in this case? Like a [Storage Reference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.storage.Reference)? I see your point, but for docs that will be used on client I guess I should stick to keep saving the full URL, right?

Comment: The path you use to build the reference.  Whether you choose to use that or the URL is completely up to you.  Or you could store both.